# How to write the equation of a line in affine space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, affine-geometry

Write the equation (in coordinates $x_1, x_2)$ of a line in $A^2$, where A denotes Affine space: passing through the point (2, −3) and parallel to the vector (5, 2).

Can we use the equation y=mx +c to find the slope and the constant to write the equation in Affine space?

Like I can get the slope as m = 2/5 since its parallel to the vector (5,2) and can get the 'c' by substituting the value of the point(2,-3) and m in the above-mentioned equation. I get the equation as $y=(2/5)x-(19/5)$.

Comment: Your method always works unless the line is vertical with equation $x = c$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if the line passes through $P=(p_1, p_2)$ and is parallel to the vector $V = (v_1, v_2)$, one can say that $X=(x_1, x_2)$ belongs to the line if the vector $\overrightarrow{PX}$ is colinear to $V$, that is to say if the determinant
\begin{equation}
0=
\begin{vmatrix}
x_1-p_1& v_1\cr
x_2 -p_2& v_2\cr
\end{vmatrix} = v_2(x_1-p_1)-v_1(x_2-p_2)
\end{equation}
This is the equation of the line. In your case
\begin{equation}
2(x_1-2) - 5(x_2+3) = 0
\end{equation}
or $2 x_1-5 x_2=19$.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your explanation. :)